# Owlready2: link string (lex) to class

Tags: python, python-3.x, owl, ontology, owlready

Is there a way to link strings to the corresponding class from an ontology?

I know `class.lex` returns the list of all lex that belong to the class. Using this method on for example the class 'AmbienceMention' returns ['vibe', 'setting', 'atmosphere', 'ambience', 'ambiance'].

I want to do the reverse, so I have the lex 'vibe' and I need to get the class 'AmbienceMention'. I can make a dictionary but this might take lot of time.

Thanks in advance!